# how to add scope for google login api

Tags: php, google-plus-signin

I am creating a google login for my website to sign up users directly from their google account. I followed this tutorial `http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php` and i'm able to access to information required. But on the request for permission page it says the website would like to have `offline access`.

How do I show it to state that I would like to access email and basic profile information.

The client creation code is as below :

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("email");
$client->addScope("profile");
```

Answer (score 3):

use this code to add scopes:

```
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/moderator'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work..

```
addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.loginhttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
```